# Spring and synchronized method to guarantee a specific number of method executions simultaneously

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, jakarta-ee, process

I'm using Spring and I would like to know how session, class and methods works (how many instance of one class I have and why).
In my case I have a `Component` class with an `async` method that calls another class with a `ProcessBuilder` inside:

```
@Component
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class ZipAndMat {
.....
......
    @Async
    public void createZipAndMat(User currentUser, String originalFileName){
        conversion(path, name, timeSample, timeout):
    }

    private void conversion(String path, String name, String timeSample, String timeout) throws Exception {        
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-XX:-UseParallelGC", "-Xss512k", "-jar", env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_CONVERSION_PATH), path, name, timeSample, timeout);        
        pb.inheritIO();        
        Process p = pb.start();        
        int error = p.waitFor();           
        if (error !=0) {            
            if (p.isAlive()) {                
                p.destroyForcibly();           
            }                        
            throw new MCRException("Error with conversion");        
        }    
    }
}
```

This is my TaskExecutor configuration:

```
@Override
public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(100);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```

I would like to control the number of processes because otherwise server may go down. I was wondering how I can achive this, using synchronization? For example I should execute 10 processes, after that other request must wait that at least one process is ended. Maybe a stupid solution may be a static variable and an active wait with a `while(i>10) this.sleep(10000)...`
Thanks

Comment: You can't achieve it with synchronization,but you can with a counting semaphore from `java.util.concurrent`.

Comment: Just configure the appropriate `TaskExecutor` and give it a max-numer of concurrent tasks you want to be able to execute. Instead of trying to do it yourself.

Comment: @EJP semaphore seems very interesting, I'm reading documentation.

Comment: @M.Deinum TaskExecutor, if I correctly understand, is useful for concurrent task in my application, not for a specific method. I would like to find more details about how Spring works with user session and TaskExecutor parameters

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the pool (ThreadPoolTaskExecutor) using by spring @Async

https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/

It'll garantee the max number of threads and inducting the number of process.

Comment: but for example, may one thread throw more processes calling conversion  method several times? How can I have maximum ten processes(so ten conversion method in execution ) and what are the weakness(what happen when Spring reach the maximum number of processes). Thanks

Comment: In your code on thread launch one process so it works. If spring use all the pool size you can configure a queue size the handle the calls.

Answer (score 1):

I believe a [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) is exactly what you are after. If you need a maximum of 10 processes running at a time, try this raw snippet:

```
@Component
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class ZipAndMat {

    private final Semaphore processes = new Semaphore(10);

    @Async
    public void createZipAndMat(User currentUser, String originalFileName){
        processes.acquire();
        conversion(path, name, timeSample, timeout);
        processes.release();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

There might be a problem with this approach though. Considering that Semaphore.acquire() is blocking, if you are submitting hundreeds of this processes and these take a long time to complete, it is possible that all the threads in the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor will block waiting for a permit. I think it is important to keep that in mind.

Comment: thanks, shouldn't the semaphore be static? In the process I have a timer and after it expires I kill the process.

Comment: Good question. Asuming your bean scope is singleton, you don't have to make the Semaphore instance static, since you will only have one instacne of that bean. If the scope of your bean is prototype, you might want to make it static.

Comment: The singleton scope is the default scope in Spring, so I think it is enough, but just to be safe I could even put the Semaphore instance static. Thanks I'll try it